# Hay alguna forma de ejecutar scripts sql en java?

Tags: java, sql

Me explico lo que quiero es ejecutar un script ya hecho en una clase java para no escribir todos los scrips de forma manual, encontré un código que se supone resuelve el problema pero los parámetros para ejecutar en la base de datos no son correctos

este es el código que encontré Cabe resaltar que el código no tiene ninguna conexión con sql

```
import java.io.*;
public class CmdExec {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {
      String line;
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
        ("psql -U username -d dbname -h serverhost -f scripfile.sql");
      BufferedReader input =
        new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

Y este es mi código en el cual ya tengo una conexión con mi base de datos y seguramente ahí es donde esta el problema

public void CallScript(){
        
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Integer key = null;
        
        try {
         String line;
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
           ("psql -U postgres -d TABLITAS -h localhost -f f_updateExistence.sql");
         BufferedReader input =
           new BufferedReader
             (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            conn = DataSourceService.getConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(p);
            ps.execute();
         while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);           
         }
         input.close();
       }
       catch (Exception err) {
         err.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
```

Comment: el `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` sirve para ejecutar comandos emulando la consola, ¿has probado la instrucción desde tu consola?

Comment: No porque  solo necesito ejecutar el archivo "scripfile.sql" dentro de la clase java

Answer (score 0):

Esto hago yo para leer y ejecutar un archivo sql

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Connection conn1 = null;
public Conexion() { 
        try {
            String url11 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
            String user1 = "root";
            String password1 = "";
            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url11, user1, password1);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Conectado php");
            }           
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:La dirección no es válida o el usuario clave");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void crearBD(String archivo){
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(archivo);
            fr = new FileReader (file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linea = br.readLine();
            String lineaBD = "";
            while(linea!=null){
                if( linea.length() != 0 ){
                    char Firstchar = linea.charAt(0);
                    if(Firstchar != '/' && Firstchar != '-' && linea.length() != 0){
                        char LastChar =  linea.charAt(linea.length() - 1);
                        if (LastChar == ';'){
                            PreparedStatement ps = conn1.prepareStatement(lineaBD + linea);
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                            ps.close();
                            lineaBD = "";
                            linea = br.readLine(); 
                        }
                        else{
                            lineaBD += linea;
                            linea = br.readLine();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        linea = br.readLine();
                    }
                }
                else
                    linea = br.readLine();               
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_ y cómo responde esto a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.